# Split pandas dataframe into blocks based on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to break dataframe into blocks from one True value to next True value:

| data | flag |
| --- | --- |
| MODS start 12/12/2020 | True |
| Some data | False |
| Some data | False |
| MODS start 30/12/2020 | True |
| Some data | False |
| Some data | False |

To

| data | flag |
| --- | --- |
| MODS start 12/12/2020 | True |
| Some data | False |
| Some data | False |

| data | flag |
| --- | --- |
| MODS start 30/12/2020 | True |
| Some data | False |
| Some data | False |

Please help

Comment: What is the logic for splitting the rows? Or is it that you want to split every 3 rows in a new df?

Comment: Logic is..Slipt dataframe from one `True` value to next `True` value

Answer (score 3):

You can use cumsum to create groups then query the datafame for each group:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':['MODS start 12/12/202','Some data', 'Some data', 'MODS starts 30/12/2020', 'Some data', 'Some data'],
                  'flag':[True, False, False, True, False, False]})

df['grp'] = df['flag'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     data   flag  grp
0    MODS start 12/12/202   True    1
1               Some data  False    1
2               Some data  False    1
3  MODS starts 30/12/2020   True    2
4               Some data  False    2
5               Some data  False    2
```

The use:

```
df.query('grp == 1')

                   data   flag  grp
0  MODS start 12/12/202   True    1
1             Some data  False    1
2             Some data  False    1
```

and

```
df.query('grp == 2')

                     data   flag  grp
3  MODS starts 30/12/2020   True    2
4               Some data  False    2
5               Some data  False    2
```

Comment: Nice! It also easily provides a variable in case OP wants to use `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
np.split(df, df.index[df.flag])[1:]
```

Here, I used `[1:]` because `numpy.split` also consider the groups before the first index, even if it's empty.

---

That said, you can also use a simple list comprehension:

```py
idx = df.index[df.flag].tolist() + [df.shape[0]]
[df.iloc[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

---

Output (both approaches):

```
                    data   flag
0  MODS start 12/12/2020   True
1              Some data  False
2              Some data  False 

                    data   flag
3  MODS start 30/12/2020   True
4              Some data  False
5              Some data  False
```

Comment: One thing is nice about your 1st answer is it splits dynamically. We don't have to actually how many numbers of groups are there if we have 50M data and you don't have a loop. Thank you

Comment: Numpy is awesome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of indices of rows with flag = True

```
true_idx = df[df['flag']==True].index
n = len(true_idx)
```

Loop over true_idx and create a list of dataframes from each true index to next

```
new_dfs_list = [df.iloc[ true_idx[i]:true_idx[i+1], :] for i in range(n-1)]
```

append last df from last true index to the tail of df

```
new_dfs_list.append(df.iloc[ true_idx[n-1]:, :])
```

access any of your new_dfs by index

```
print(new_dfs_list[-1])
```